# How to calculate difference between 2 dates when it goes to past? VBA, EXCEL

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with calculating difference between 2 dates where first is older than second.

For example: I want to find difference between

```
 5.5.2015 and 1.11.2014
```

I used function

```
 =IF((A(DATEDIF(B12,$W$3,"M")<=12,RANK(Q12,Q:Q)<=11)),Q12;0)
```

but the function is limited only to situations where the second date is higher than the first one.

I want to know whether B12 is within last 12 months from given date. If it is, then I want to calculate with it.
Is there any way to calculate backwards in excel or VBA?
Thank you.

Comment: `=IF(DATEDIF(Min(B12,$W$3),Max(B12,$W$3),"M")<=12,Q12,0)` - one possible way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old post already but for anyone who needs this...

```
Function FindDateDiff(myDate1 As Date, myDate2 As Date) As String
Dim myYears As Long, myMonths As Long, myDays As Long
Dim yearString As String, monthString As String, dayString As String, FinalString As String

If myDate1 > myDate2 Then
       myYears = Year(myDate1) - Year(myDate2)
       myMonths = Month(myDate1) - Month(myDate2)
       myDays = Day(myDate1) - Day(myDate2)
       
       If myDays < 0 Then
              myMonths = myMonths - 1
              myDays = Day(WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(myDate1, 0)) - Abs(myDays) - 1
       End If
       
Else
       myYears = Year(myDate2) - Year(myDate1)
       myMonths = Month(myDate2) - Month(myDate1)
       myDays = Day(myDate2) - Day(myDate1)
       
       If myDays < 0 Then
              myMonths = myMonths - 1
              myDays = Day(WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(myDate2, 0)) - Abs(myDays) - 1
       End If

End If

If myMonths < 0 Then
       myYears = myYears - 1
       myMonths = 12 - Abs(myMonths)
End If

If myYears = 0 Then
       yearString = ""
ElseIf myYears = 1 Then
       yearString = myYears & " year, "
ElseIf myYears > 1 Then
       yearString = myYears & " years, "
End If
                            
If myMonths = 0 Then
       monthString = ""
ElseIf myMonths = 1 Then
       monthString = myMonths & " month, "
ElseIf myMonths > 1 Then
       monthString = myMonths & " months, "
End If
                         
If myDays = 0 Then
       dayString = ""
ElseIf myDays = 1 Then
       dayString = myDays & " day"
ElseIf myDays > 1 Then
       dayString = myDays & " days"
End If

FinalString = yearString & monthString & dayString

If Right(FinalString, 2) = ", " Then FinalString = Left(FinalString, Len(FinalString) - 2)

FindDateDiff= FinalString

End Function
```

Just paste this function in a new module in the workbook and you can start calling this function. '=FindDateDiff(A1,B1)'
This function only require 2 dates as arguments and the order doesn't matter.

I've tested this function with both UK and US format, both works exactly the same.

I used DateDiff before, but the calculation for days and months returns an incorrect value and could be very confuse sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

In VBA use the same function.

```
NoOfDays = DateDiff("D", DATE1, DATE2)
```

NoOfDays  returns either positive or negative value depending on the dates

Comment: Siva the the syntax should be DateDiff(Start_DATE1, End_DATE2,"D") http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datedif.php

Comment: @Linga, You are correct when we are using it as formula in Cell. But in VBA code its what i have given. Give a try.

Answer (score 0):

I have it solved by using ISERROR

```
=IF(ISERROR(DATEDIF(RC[-16],R3C23,""M"")<=12),0,RC[-1])
```